# Filtering images by category, RSS reader

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, collections, rss, merge

I found a great RSS reader which gets only images.
Location: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/08/fetching-picasa-images-through-rss-in.html

Thing I cant figure out is how to make that reader filter and show images from feed only by desired category. I am not planing to use that reader for Picasa.

RSS feed I use: http://www.zimo.co/feed/

---

I created an ObservableCollection

```
ObservableCollection<FeedItem> categories;

    public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set
        {
            categories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Categories");
        }
    }
```

and updated the code as following

```
private void Feed(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                var xmlElement = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                FeedItems.Clear();
//added code for pulling all categories for every item in the feed
                foreach (var katItem in from value
                                     in xmlElement.Elements("channel").Elements("item").Elements("category")
                                        select value.Value
                                            into xCategory
                                            where xCategory != null
                                            select new FeedItem { Category = xCategory })
                {
                    Categories.Add(katItem);



                }

                    foreach (var feedItem in from value
                                                 in xmlElement.Elements("channel").Elements("item")
                                             select value.Element("enclosure")
                                                 into xEnclosure
                                                 where xEnclosure != null
                                                 select xEnclosure.Attribute("url")
                                                     into xUrl
                                                     where xUrl != null
                                                     select new FeedItem { Link = xUrl.Value }
                                                       )
                    {

                                            FeedItems.Add(feedItem);
                    }

            }


        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

This way I have a Collection (Categories) in which I get all the categories from each item in the feed. Thing I would like to know. Is it possible to merge these two collections and then filter the new collection by desired category so I only get desired images out?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse out the images on your own. With a Picasa feed, you get explicit links to images that later can be bound to an `Image` control. With your feed, I don't see explicit image links.

Comment: but this reader works on my feed as it is.
are u telling it cannot be adapted for filtration?

Comment: It can, as long as you figure out a way to get the image links from inside the feed.

Comment: the reader reads entire feed and takes images from it only.
now I would need a loop for filtration.

correct me if I figured the RSS reader code wrong, im not very experienced programmer.